# Pass Dynamic URL Params from CMS Link to Paperform.io form

Tags: javascript, web, webview, request

In my app I have a support web page located at the `/support` endpoint which is setup by an internal CMS tool that applies the link to a 'More' tab in the app and opens in a WebView. I want to prefill data on the support page with the user's name, email, and current app version to accurately record bugs/issues from users. The support form is generated by paperform.io and accepts URL params with specific keys that map to each input field and automatically prefills. What I need to figure out is how to send those params from the app when the user clicks the support link.

Can I set it up so the app generates the query string and applies it to the link when it is clicked? Or do I have to handle the query string with JavaScript on the web page since the link is static from the CMS tool.

To summarize:

1. I have a CMS tool that applies links to the 'More' tab of my app.
2. One of those links is 'myapp.com/support' which loads a paperform.io web form.
3. I want the form data to be prefilled based on params from the app.
4. When a user clicks the link in app, instead of hitting `myapp.com/support` I want to include parameters like `myapp.com/support?name=Jeff&email=Jeff@stackoverflow.com&appVersion=iOS+v15+App+v2`

Question: Can I include the parameters with the request made by clicking the link or do I need to handle and prefill the data with JavaScript on the page itself?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean papersurvey.io or paperform.co?

If paperform.co, then the answer is via Hidden Fields. Choose "Hidden" as field type, and in the configuration of the field, enter the parameter you want to capture in "Pre-fill Key".